# difference between set of tuples ,remove common elements

Tags: python-3.x

`R=[['dafdwsf','fafwfwe','fedfwefw','kmlknkfwe'],['cdcdcewfqedq','aasdecercre','hhkklkmlk','testing'],['nvnnkv','mmffwe','ljfljfwe']]`

`S=[['hhkklkmlk','cdcdcewfqedq'],['fwlkmfw','mmffwe','ljfljfwe'],['dafdwsf','fafwfwe','fedfwefw','kmlknkfwe']]`

If have converted lists of lists to set of tuples

`set(map(tuple,R))-set(map(tuple,S))`

returns

`{('cdcdcewfqedq', 'aasdecercre', 'hhkklkmlk','testing'),('nvnnkv', 'mmffwe', 'ljfljfwe')}`

Im looking for ways to get :

`{('aasdecercre','testing'),('nvnnkv')}`

I have read here to sort the tuples before creating set but still not getting the desired output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can flatten the lists R and S:

`r = [item for sublist in R for item in sublist]`

`s = [item for sublist in S for item in sublist]`
(different ways to flatten a nested list [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/952914/how-to-make-a-flat-list-out-of-list-of-lists))
and then create the sets using

`x = set(tuple(r))-set(tuple(s))`.

Then regroup all values based on parent list(this implementation depends on size of your lists/sets, if its only a few, this will work):

`r2 = [ [i for  i in j if i in x] for j in R]`

and then convert to tuples:

`r2 = [tuple(i) for i in r2 if len(i)>0]`

Comment: Sorry if it wasnt clear , Flattening would not retain individual lists . Let me add that condition in the question

Comment: so you want all common elements removed but want to keep original groupings intact?

Comment: Then can you also update the question with exact thing you want instead of just an example

Comment: I have updated the example data set and edited the question heading , hope that is your request

Comment: the parent lists are a couple of thousand in size , will see how this works